# ASP Razor calling asmx webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, razor

I have ASP.Net WebForm project with .asmx webservices inside, I added some ASP Razor files (.vbhtml),
my question is, how do I call these web services from (.vbhtml) files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more common to make such calls in controllers and then pass the data to views.

If you insist doing it on views (.vbhtml), you have two options,

1. Make the call in embedded VB.NET code, so the web service is invoked on the server.
2. Make the call in embedded JavaScript code, so that web service invoked from the web browser.